# Capistrano 3: way to handle different deploy flows

Tags: capistrano3

I am new to Capistrano, but I have succeded on getting it working for a custom deploy. I have to deploy Moodle to a cluster with an auto-scaling group in AWS and one or more static servers.

It works great! I have managed to alter the flow with custom tasks to put my site on maintenance and clear cache without problems:

```
namespace :moodle do

  desc 'Save config.php from current release directory'   task :'save-config'
    on roles(:web) do
      execute :sudo, :cp, shared_path.join('config.php'), release_path
      execute :sudo, :chown, 'www-data-aulatp:www-data', release_path.join('config.php') 
    end
  end

  desc 'Copy config.php to release directory'   task :'restore-config' do
    on roles(:web) do
      execute :sudo, :cp, shared_path.join('config.php'), release_path
      execute :sudo, :chown, 'www-data-aulatp:www-data', release_path.join('config.php') 
    end
  end

  desc 'Enable maintenance mode on Moodle site'   task :'enable-maintenance' do
    on roles(:admin) do
      execute :sudo, '-u', 'www-data-aulatp', '/usr/bin/php7.0', current_path.join('admin', 'cli', 'maintenance.php'), '--enable'
    end
  end

  desc 'Disable maintenance mode on Moodle site'   task :'disable-maintenance' do
    on roles(:admin) do
      execute :sudo, '-u', 'www-data-aulatp', '/usr/bin/php7.0', current_path.join('admin', 'cli', 'maintenance.php'), '--disable'
    end
  end

  desc 'Purge all internal Moodle caches'   task :'purge-caches' do
    on roles(:admin) do
      execute :sudo, '-u', 'www-data-aulatp', '/usr/bin/php7.0', current_path.join('admin', 'cli', 'purge_caches.php')
    end   
  end
end

before   'deploy:starting',    'moodle:save-config'
before   'deploy:updated',     'moodle:enable-maintenance' 
after    'deploy:updated',     'moodle:restore-config' 
after    'deploy:finished',    'moodle:enable-maintenance' 
after    'deploy:finished',    'moodle:disable-maintenance' 
after    'deploy:finished',    'moodle:purge-caches'
```

The problem is, sometimes I will need to make quick deploys, a small patch that does not need enabling and disabling maintenance mode or purging caches.

Would it be posible with capistrano?

As a posible alternative, I have been looking also to [capistrano-patch](https://github.com/railsware/capistrano-patch), a way to deploy a simple patch to every server without creating a full deploy process. It looks like it has not ben updated for some years and I suppose it will not work with capistrano 3. Any similar ideas to do HOTFIX with Capistrano 3?

Comment: I added an answer below, but did not comment on capistrano-patch. I don't know of a Capistrano 3 equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use environment variables to state that something needs to be bypassed. E.g., you could run your deploy with `NO_CACHE_PURGE=true cap production deploy` and then wrap the relevant code with something like:

```
desc 'Purge all internal Moodle caches'
task :'purge-caches' do
  if ENV['NO_CACHE_PURGE'].nil?
    on roles(:admin) do
      execute :sudo, '-u', 'www-data-aulatp', '/usr/bin/php7.0', current_path.join('admin', 'cli', 'purge_caches.php')
    end
  else
    puts 'Skipping purge-caches due to env variable'
  end
end
```

If you know Ruby well, and you want to automate this, you could probably write a method which would simplify some of this (the following code is untested):

```
def disableable_task(*args)
  if ENV[args[:env_name]].nil?
    task(args)
  else
    puts "Skipping #{args[0]} due to #{args[:env_name]} environment variable being set"
end

desc 'Purge all internal Moodle caches'
disableable_task :'purge-caches', env_name: 'NO_CACHE_PURGE' do
  on roles(:admin) do
    execute :sudo, '-u', 'www-data-aulatp', '/usr/bin/php7.0', current_path.join('admin', 'cli', 'purge_caches.php')
  end
end
```